# Texlive: ! LaTeX Error: File `IEEEtrantools.sty' not found

Tags: packages, texlive

I want to compile this file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
•
\end{document}
```

But get that error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `IEEEtrantools.sty' not found.
```

How can I install this package?

I installed texlive the following way on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive texlive-lang-german texlive-latex-extra
sudo apt-get install texmaker
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/tools

Comment: You probably saw https://www.tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html ... which is not too informative, unfortunately. Perhaps have a closer look again. // If you work with MiKTeX, it will ask to install unknown packages.

Comment: `apt-file search IEEEtrantools.sty` suggests installing the `texlive-publishers` package...

Comment: This is one of the disadvantages of using texlive from Ubuntu, it is split up into Ubuntu bundles and it is gard to know what to install. Pauls suggestion of using `apt-file` is very useful. Just remember to prime it using `sudo apt-file update ` from time to time

Comment: @PaulGaborit thanks, that solved my problem. But I don't understand what `apt-file search IEEEtrantools.sty` should be doing? If I run it in Terminal it returns nothing. Even though I used `sudo apt-file update` first.

Comment: `apt-file search <filename>` is supposed to return the list of packages installing the file named `<filename>`...